# Localstack InvalidAccessKeyId

Tags: amazon-web-services, localstack

In the [documentation for localstack](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/integrations/aws-cli/#configuring-a-custom-profile) it says to set up my AWS credentials as so:

**~/.aws/config**

```
[profile localstack]
region=us-east-1
output=json
endpoint_url = http://localhost:4566
```

**~/.aws/credentials**

```
[localstack]
aws_access_key_id=test
aws_secret_access_key=test
```

When I try and run `aws --profile localstack s3 ls` I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
AWS CLI version `aws-cli/2.12.2 Python/3.11.4 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off`

Localstack is running.

Comment: What AWS CLI version are you using?

Comment: And it appears that it is trying to connect to the real AWS. Is your LocalStack container running?

Comment: `aws-cli/2.12.2 Python/3.11.4 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off` and localstack is definitely running

Comment: This seems like an issue with the AWS CLI v2 not able to pick up the profiles. Can I suggest trying awslocal (pip install awscli-local) to use AWS CLI with LocalStack?